# Why some of AT Commands are Slow?

Tags: at-command

Why some AT Commands like AT+COPS=? are too slow and sometimes they doesn't response ? COPS=? give me the near PLMNs but sometimes it takes 2 minutes and sometimes it doesn't an response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some AT commands forces the modem to communicate with network(s).

For example dial command `ATD` takes time because network must establish a call.

`AT+COPS=?` takes time, because the response information is not cached in the modem. 
So the modem need to scan the information from radio networks of the current location.

If `AT+COPS=?` does not respond, please double check your source codes / configuration for too short timeouts.